# Verilog: cannot be driven by primitives or continuous assignment

Tags: verilog

Could someone help me figure out why I am getting such an error. The code below implements a 4 bit shift register adder which takes one bit at a time from each register computes the sum of the 2 bits using a full adder stores the carry (previous) and then pushes the result of the full adder back to first shift register.thus at the end of 4 clock cycles the result (sum) is in the first register

Error i am getting 
Reg cannot be driven by primitives or continuous assignment.

CODE:

```
module FADDER(s,c,x,y,z);
    input x,y,z;
    output s,c;
    reg s,c;

    always @(x or y or z)
    begin
        s = (x^y)^z;
        c = (x & y) | (y & z) | (z & x);
    end 
endmodule

module shift_reg_add(a, b,clr, clk);
    output [3:0] a,b;
    reg [3:0] a,b;
    input clr, clk;

    reg carr = 1'b0;
    wire w1, newcarr;
    wire w2,w3;

    assign w2 = a[0];
    assign w3 = b[0];
    FADDER f(w1, newcarr, w2, w3, carr);

    always @(posedge clk) begin
        a <= {1'b0, a[3:1]};
        a[3] <= w1;
        b <= {1'b0, b[3:1]};
        carr <= newcarr; 
    end
endmodule

module testbench;
    reg [3:0] a,b;
    reg clr, clk;

    shift_reg_add s1(a,b,clr,clk);

    initial begin
        clk = 0;
        clr = 1;
    end

    always begin
        #2 clk = ~clk;
    end

    initial $monitor($time, " clr %b a = %b b = %b prev_carr = %b", clr, a, b, s1.carr);

    initial begin
        a = 4'b0101;
        b = 4'b1100;
        clr = 1'b1;
    end
endmodule
```

Comment: Can you tell us what your error is and what you're expecting your output to be? (Please include this with your question by editing it)

Comment: Any particular reason you're using blocking assignments in one always block and non-blocking in another?

Comment: You still need to let us know what error you're seeing. What has the compiler told you? What is the functionality of this code? It kind of looks like a binary adder and then you're bit shifting your product but I don't know exactly what you're trying to do afterwards. _Failing to provide this information could lead me to suspect that you're just copying and pasting someone else's code and then expecting it to work... Then that would make me refuse to answer this question since I wouldn't support plagiarism and/or academic dishonesty._

Comment: Your usage of blocking and non-blocking assignments is correct, but you don't know why. That is suspicious!

Comment: `shift_reg_add s1(a,b,clr,clk);` <<---- You declare `a` and `b` as `reg` in your test-bench, but then try to drive them from outputs of your `shift_reg_add` module. As such you will get an error saying a `reg` cannot be driven via continous assignment. Change `a` and `b` to `wire` in your testbench. This would be an answer, but the question is on hold.

Comment: I fail to understand why declaring a and b as reg in my testbench is an error, like I am not clear on this driving concept. Appreciate if someone could explain it in simple words or provide a good source from where i can get some clarity

Comment: http://go.mentor.com/wire-vs-reg

Answer (score 2):

Your problem comes down to not correctly using `wire` vs `reg` in your test bench code.

Specifically:

```
reg [3:0] a,b;
shift_reg_add s1(a,b,clr,clk);
```

You declare `a` and `b` as `reg` in your test-bench, but then try to drive them from outputs of your `shift_reg_add` module.

A `reg` (register) type variable can only be driven using a procedural block, that is primarily `always`, and `initial`. You cannot assign a value to a `reg` through continuous assignment.

A `wire` (net) type variable can be used to connect signals together using continuous assignment. This is either the `assign` statement or by being driven from the output of a module as in your case.

As such in your test bench, you will get an error saying a `reg` cannot be driven via continous assignment.

Change `a` and `b` to `wire` in your testbench.

---

Think of it this way, you declared your outputs as `reg` inside the module, this is fine because they are being driven from procedural blocks in the module. You now need to take what is essentially the output of your register, and connect it up in your test bench. This simply requires a net connection or `wire1.